# jQuery add animation to element during another animation

Tags: jquery, animation

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDz4v/)

We have some div slowly changin its `height`. When div is clicked, it moves a little `left`.

What I want to do is that when you click div during its `height` animation it will begin moving left immediatetly without affecting height animation/stopping it etc.

So in fact there will be animation of height and of position at once then.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528563/jquery-animate-when-another-animation-is-in-progress

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you change `5000` to `{ queue: false, duration: 5000 }`, it will work. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FDz4v/1/

Comment: Damn, that's way better than the solution I was writing up.  But that's why I come here...to learn!

Comment: @Javalsu I was originally making it much more complicated, but then I remembered the `queue` attribute. It's helpful with animation stuff.

Comment: I just posted my answer...since I already made the fiddle.  I was using two divs an inner and a wrapper and animating them separately.  But the queue attribute is pretty useful, and something I didn't know about before. Thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/FDz4v/2/

I know the other solution is much better than mine :)  But here is another method.  You can use two divs and animate them separately.

```
$('#wrapperdiv').click(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {left: '+=50px'});
});

$('#innerdiv').animate({'height':'800px'},5000);
```